# Finding First and Second Date per Group

Tags: sas

I would like to find the first and second earliest date per group.

I'm used to doing this in the SQL `SELECT` statement, for example in Oracle using the `NTH_VALUE` function. I am unaware of a similar function in SAS proc SQL.

The SAS `RANK` proc may work but I cannot get the values outputted as I want them.

Example data:

```
PERSON_ID   DT
1           03Oct2019
1           14Oct2019
1           23Oct2019
2           08Oct2019
2           08Oct2019
2           10Oct2019
3           05Oct2019
```

Desired output:

```
PERSON_ID DT1       DT2
1         03Oct2019 14Oct2019
2         08Oct2019 10Oct2019
3         05Oct2019
```

I started with something like below which assigns the rank; however, I'd like to output the first two ranks pivoted to one row, not the rank itself on multiple rows.

```
proc rank data=have out=want(where=(dt_rank in (1,2))) ties=low ;
    by person_id;
  var dt;
   ranks dt_rank;
run;

PERSON_ID   DT        DT_RANK
1           03Oct2019 1
1           14Oct2019 2
2           08Oct2019 1
2           10Oct2019 2
3           05Oct2019 1
```

Comment: Please include any attempts you've made to solve this issue so far. Sort and BY group processing are good starter approaches. [ask]

Comment: You just haven't added the last step.  A simple transform from tall to wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SQL solution

```
title data we have;
data have  ;
infile datalines firstobs=2;
input 
    @01 PERSON_ID 1.  
    @11 DT        date9.;
format DT date9.;
datalines;
----+----1----+----2----+----3
1         03Oct2019
1         14Oct2019
1         23Oct2019
2         08Oct2019
2         08Oct2019
2         10Oct2019
3         05Oct2019
;
proc print;
run;

title want;
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select  H1.person_id
        ,   min(H1.DT) as dt1 format=date9.
        ,   min(H2.DT) as dt2 format=date9.
    from have as H1 left join have as H2
    on H1.person_id eq H2.person_id and H1.DT lt H2.DT
    group by H1.person_id;
proc print;
run;
```

Comment: Several valid answers but I ended up using this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A solution in your programming style:

```
title data we have;
data have  ;
infile datalines firstobs=2;
input 
    @01 PERSON_ID 1.  
    @11 DT        date9.;
format DT date9.;
datalines;
----+----1----+----2----+----3
1         03Oct2019
1         14Oct2019
1         23Oct2019
2         08Oct2019
2         08Oct2019
2         10Oct2019
3         05Oct2019
;
```

Remove duplicates

```
proc sort nodup 
    data=have 
    out=sorted;

    by person_id dt;
proc print;
run;
```

Set first and second side by side  (remove third and later with the keep statement)

```
title transpose;
proc transpose prefix=DT
    data=sorted
    out=want (keep=PERSON_ID DT1 DT2);

    by PERSON_ID;
    var dt;
proc datasets nolist;
    modify want;
        format dt: date9.;
proc print;
run;
```

Verify correctness

```
title benchmark;
Data Bench ;
infile datalines truncover firstobs=2;
input 
    @01 PERSON_ID 1.  
    @11 DT1       date9.
    @21 DT2       date9.;
format DT: date9.;
datalines;
----+----1----+----2----+----3
1         03Oct2019 14Oct2019
2         08Oct2019 10Oct2019
3         05Oct2019
;
proc print;
run;
title compare;
proc compare
    base=bench
    comp=want;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the oracle rank function

```
select person_id
     , min (case rank when 1 then dt end)   as dt_1
     , min (case rank when 2 then dt end)   as dt_2
from ( select person_id
            , dt
            , rank() over (partition by PERSON_ID order by DT) as rank
       from person_table
     )
group by person_id
order by person_id
```

you can combine this with the pivot function to convert rows to colums for the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Groupwise processing of data can be performed using an explicit **DOW** loop, in which the `SET` and `BY` statements are nested inside the loop.

- At the top of the implicit loop the variables `dt1` and `dt2` are implicitly reset
- At the bottom of the loop a single row, corresponding to the group, is output implicitly.

```
data have; input 
id date: date9.; format date date9.; datalines;
1  03Oct2019
1  14Oct2019
1  23Oct2019
2  08Oct2019
2  08Oct2019
2  10Oct2019
3  05Oct2019
run;

data want (keep=id dt1 dt2);
  do until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;

    attrib dt1 dt2 length=4 format=date9.;

    if missing(dt1) then dt1 = date;
    if missing(dt2) and date ne dt1 then dt2=date;
  end;
run;
```